# Does Terraform AWS provider allow to create AWS Parallel Cluster instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-parallelcluster

I have checked the latest Terraform AWS provider (4.64.0) docs here:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs

But I can't find AWS Parallel Cluster related resources on the list in the docs for the latest version.

I would like to provision an instance of AWS Parallel Cluster writing in my Terraform code something like:

```
resource "aws_parallel_cluster" "my_cluster" {
...
```

But nothing similar doesn't seem to exist in Terraform AWS provider.

Does it mean AWS Parallel Cluster is not supported by Terraform yet?
Or does the support exist but simply missing its place in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, as AWS Parallel Cluster is not an actual AWS service, which means it **doesn't have** AWS API interface which TF would have to use to interact with it.

Comment: I can see that under the hood AWS Parallel Cluster validates cluster configs, then composes and applies a Cloud Formation template.
Some of the activities can be done via AWS API.
Do you mean the very composition of a Cloud Formation template would bear a lot more (similar logic to what Parallel Cluster does) than simply using AWS API?